# Why does "self is not defined" on line 13 appear? I don't seem to violate any of the paradigm rules

Tags: python, class, oop, error-handling, self

Can't access `self.transitions` inside of the method

```
class Finite_automaton:
    def __init__(self,initial_state,final_states,alphabet,transitions,state):
        self.initial_state = initial_state
        self.final_states = final_states
        self.alphabet = alphabet
        self.transitions = transitions
        self.state = state

 
    def fa_type():
        counts=[]
        for transition in self.transitions:  // here, this self is not defined
            cs=transition[0]+transition[1]
            if cs in counts:
                return False
            else:
                counts.append(cs)
        return True
```

accessing the class attribute should've worked

Comment: `self` needs to be a parameter to the function.  `def fa_type(self):`

Comment: Where do you believe you defined `self` anywhere in scope in that function? There clearly is no variable named `self` defined there

Comment: `self` is not a  special keyword that refers to the invoking instance. It's just the conventional name for the first parameter of an instance method, which is automatically supplied a value when the method is invoked thanks to the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: @chepner Please post that as an answer. I think too many people starting out see `self` as some kind of magic due in no small part to it being apparently magically passed around.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is not a keyword used to represent the invoking instance of a method. It is "just" the conventional name of the first parameter of an instance method; the argument assigned to this parameter is passed implicitly via the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). As such, you *must* define a function intended to be used as an instance method with a parameter to receive this first argument. (Whether you call it `self` or something else is really up to you, but there is little reason *not* to follow the convention of calling it `self`.)

---

A little more detail on the descriptor protocol. Any type that defines a `__get__` method is a descriptor; the `function` type is one of those types. Whenever you access such a value a class or instance attribute, you get back not the actual function, but the result of the function's `__get__` method. Thus, in the code

```
f = Finite_automaton()
f.fs_type()
```

the attribute access `f.fs_type` does not produce the function. It produces an instance of the `method` type, because `f.fs_type` is equivalent to

```
Finite_automaton.__dict__['fs_type'].__get__(f, Finite_automaton)
```

This `method` object is little more than a wrapper around `Finite_automaton.fs_type` and `f`. When you *call* the `method` instance, it takes whatever argument you give *it*, and passes `f` and those arguments to `Finite_automaton.fs_type`, resulting in

```
f.fs_type() -> Finite_automaton.__dict__['fs_type'].__get__(f, Finite_automaton)()
            -> Finite_automaton.fs_type(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `self` as the first argument of the method:

```py
def fa_type(self):
    # method's body comes here...
```